# Conditional formatting VBA not highlighting cell in a specific cell in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I had a quick question about the conditional formatting part of my code,

the rest of the code works perfect but when I get to the conditional formatting part,  the row I wanted to highlight doesn't. I want the row with to be highlighted based on a value that is on cell H5 on the copysheet area.

cell H5 has the formala =MAX(IF(ISERROR("L8:L2500,"",L8:2500") which finds the max value in range L

is there any way to apply conditional formatting to search for that max value?

```
Sub Search()

Dim vCrit As Variant
Dim filtersheet As Worksheet
Dim copysheet As Worksheet
Dim rngCrit As Range
Dim rngList As Range



Set filtersheet = Worksheets("Datalog")
Set copysheet = Worksheets("Line Inquiry")


filtersheet.Unprotect


Set rngCrit = filtersheet.Range("$A$7:$L$2500").CurrentRegion
Set rngList = copysheet.Range("B5")



vCrit = Sheets("Datalog").Range("O3")

copysheet.Range("A8:K2500").Clear


With filtersheet
rngCrit.AutoFilter _
Field:=3, _
Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(vCrit), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues



rngCrit.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
copysheet.Range("A7").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
filtersheet.AutoFilterMode = False


filtersheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

copysheet.Range("A8:L2500").FormatConditions.Delete

With copysheet.Range("$A8:$L8").FormatConditions.Add( _
Type:=xlExpression, _
Formula1:="=$H$5=$L8")
.Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
.Font.Color = RGB(0, 97, 0)


    End With

End With

'returning to original sheet
copysheet.Range("B5").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you aware that the formula you provided [=MAX(..)] is wrong?

Comment: Because you are using a *relative* row number in the CF formula, you need to select a cell in that row in your code before you apply the CF.

Comment: how is the max formula wrong is it does what I need it to do? im confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do your formatting in your code.  Something like this.

```
if somecondition then
    copysheet.Range("I" & lRow).Font.ColorIndex = 3
End if
```

Comment: If Range("$H$5") = Range("$L8") Then
    copysheet.Range("l" & lRow).Font.ColorIndex = 3

Comment: @Sergio Oropeza You need to change the range in the copysheet.  
If Range("$H$5") = Range("$L8") Then copysheet.Range("$H$5").Font.ColorIndex = 3